# How can I show the duplicate data in Asp.Net MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, database, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, uiviewcontroller

This table has all employee data call center agents like Mark and Sara. Mark saved 3 rows and Sara saved 5 rows. I would like to show Mark 5 and Sara 3.

I am using a controller as shown in the following code:

```
//this code to poes data to view 
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckEmployee(Chart obj)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MAHGOUBND4;Initial Catalog=CTC_Mahgoub;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=8008989;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cs INNER JOIN( select EmployeeName FROM cs GROUP BY EmployeeName  HAVING Count(*) > 1) " +
                " As DuplicateRows ON DuplicateRows.EmployeeName = cs.EmployeeName)",con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", obj.EmployeeName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DuplicateRows", obj.DuplicateRows);

            return Json( JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my class

```
namespace Asp.NETMVCCRUD.Models
{
    public class Chart
    {
       
            public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
            public int DuplicateRows { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

And in my view DataTable

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Popup, dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        dataTable = $("#employeeTable").DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/chart/CheckEmployee",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [

                { "data": "EmployeeName", "name": "EmployeeName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "DuplicateRows", "name": "DuplicateRows", "autoWidth": true },

            ],
            "orderable": false,
            "searchable": false,
            "width": "150px",
            "dom": "Bfrtip",
            
            "language": {

                "emptyTable": "No data found, Please click on <b>Add New</b> Button"
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I am show this error:

**DataTables warning: table id=employeeTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**

Can you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with your code:

1. In Controller Action, what are you passing in return statement? Empty Json( JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)?
2. Make sure you have a tag associated with 'employeeTable'
3. Make sure your query return only required result and not all columns in case of a long list of columns.
4. Your action attribute has HTTPPOST but your ajax has 'GET'

Would be helpful for you if you first go through these errors first.